# Is my compilation false?

Tags: compiling, executable

I thought my compliation was okay because no errors were printed out, yet when I try to run the executable, he tells me that it's unreachable...

```
coppan12@b048-08:~$ gcc -Wall prog.c -o prog
coppan12@b048-08:~$ prog
La commande « prog » est introuvable
```

any hint?

Comment: Your current directory is not in your PATH (the list of directories which are searched for executable files), so you have to tell exactly which file you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
./prog
```

to run `prog` in the current working directory, as `.` is typically not (nor should be) in `PATH`.

Also, a `Makefile` is perhaps much more sensible, as then you can simply type `make test` and have the program built (if necessary) and tested:

```
prog: prog.c

test: prog
        echo blah de blah | ./prog
```

A `Makefile` can also integrate with `emacs` or `vim` based testing, among other advantages... (disadvantage: `Makefile` use tabs, so ensure any rules are tabbed in, not with spaces, sigh.)

Comment: Ow, that's works! Just two dumb questions, why `prog` isn't in the current directory by default (or the current directory not in the path)? and why is `.` not in `PATH`?

Comment: Security issues, mostly, as running random programs from the current directory could allow a malicious local user to make you run arbitrary code at worst, or at best something accidentally gets run and then things break...

Comment: Also, a `Makefile` is probably much more handy than manually typing in the appropriate compiler line and so forth...

Comment: And what about `$PATH &...`. By changing the path I read that it could help calling my program awithout having to use the unhandy `./`?

Comment: For a case study of why adding the current directory to a search path is a stunningly bad idea, consider: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-5652